# How to extract string from sentence using sub-string and position function?

Tags: substring, cognos

I have to extract a value from string and I am working on cognos application that doesn't support regex. It has some built in functions like `substring` and `position`

My string is similar to

`/content/folder[@name='ab_Salary Reports']/folder[@name='INT Salary Reports']/folder[@name='INT Sal Sche']/jobDefinition[@name='Salary Rep R025']`

And I have to extract **`Salary Rep R025`**, ie. the last name value.
Static substring will not work because string is variable.

Comment: What language are you using? How does your code run?

Comment: Application supports sql server functions and `substring`, `position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the position function to locate the starting and ending point of your target substring.  Try

```
position('/jobDefinition', [pathstring])
```

combined with substring:

```
substring( [pathstring], position('/jobDefinition', [pathstring]) + 22, length([pathstring]) - position('/jobDefinition', [pathstring]) + 22)
```

This will start 22 characters after where it finds /jobDefinition, meaning it will start just past '/jobDefinition[@name='', and will proceed for the remaining length of the string, determined by subtracting the starting point from the full length.

You may need to adjust by +1 or -1 in order to include or exclude your quotes.

Also note that this is using Report Studio functions.  The source for Cognos reports is queries on tables, so you may have native functions available depending on your source.  For example, most of the reports I work with come out of an Oracle database, so I can use oracle string functions instead of Report Studio functions.  They work better, and are processed on the database side rather than on the Cognos Dispatcher, which is always faster.